# Kubuntu will not start

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 on my old laptop and am happy with it. So I installed Kubuntu to my main desktop computer's second hard disk to use full-time as my OS. I then selected that disk as my first boot option in my motherboard settings, and restarted my computer.

Kubuntu shows this message:

```
[ 0.269691] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xda56d000-0xda56dfff flags 0x200] vs da 56d000 4000
[ 0.269704] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xda5 6d000-0xda56dfff]
_
```

Then asks me to decrypt my drive, flashing the Kubuntu logo, then after successful decryption returns to the error message and nothing further happens. I gave up after 10 minutes and rebooted into Windows.

I also tried installing it to a USB drive, and get the same error when trying to start.

What is going wrong please? How do I fix this?

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks. Why? It works with drive encryption on my laptop, and on a VM on my desktop. I don't want to have any unencrypted drives. Let's say I install without encryption and it works - I've learnt nothing about fixing the problem, and I won't use the OS.

Comment: I might have been wrong - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422454/acpi-region-does-not-cover-the-entire-command-response-buffer).

Comment: Thank you I will try disable secure boot soon and report back. Need to eat lunch

Comment: Yeah - disabling TPM/Fast boot/Secure boot might be worth a try. 

Comment: Ok, I tried disabling TPM/Fast boot one by one and it didn't help. I can't see any way to disable secure boot on my machine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. If you press shift and escape after the BIOS loads you will see the Ubuntu boot menu. There you can choose continue with normal boot and everything will work. Once booted, you can download all driver updates, which fixed the problem. I'll log a bug with Ubuntu for them to fix whatever is happening here. What a horrible experience of Linux.